# Преобразование Xlsx файла в XML

Tags: c#, xml, xlsx

Всем привет.
Требуется преобразовать Xlsx файл в Xml по аналогичной структуре файла XML(Скрин во вложении).
Описание задачи:
Считать данные из Excel-документа "ФайлСИсходнымиДанными.xls" и записать в xml-файл (по аналогии с файлом "ФайлРезультат.xml").

При заполнения тегов RootXml, SchemaVersion, Period, Source, Form руководствуйтесь xml-файлом.

Тег Column - содержит номера и названия столбцов из xls-файла, за исключением столбца 2(Код счета бюджетного учета) .

Тег Document содержит атрибут ПлСч11, который принимает значения столбца 2(Код счета бюджетного учета), но при добавлении вначало символа "1" и обнулении последних трёх символов.
Например, столбец 2 содержит значение "20111510", то значение ПлСч11 будет "120111000".

Тег Data содержит атрибут СТРОКА, который принимает значения по возрастанию, начиная с "001" в пределах тега Document.

Тег <Data СТРОКА="960"> всегда присутствует в теге Document. Содержит итоговые суммы числовых столбцов.

Подскажите откуда начинать копать для реализации.
Скрин исходника  XLSX:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Скрин примера XML:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно не получается? Самый простой способ - сохранить файл в CSV.  А в приложении десереализовать данные и потом сереализовать в XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Data; //System.Data.Common.dll
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema; //System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Парсите Excel-документы через:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.ReadXml()
```

Выполняете обход строк/столбцов:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        //Console.Write("{0},", row[column]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Ищите строку с стоблцами: `1,2,3,4,5,6`

После неё идут полезные данные, которые вы складываете в экземпляры класса:

```
class UseFullData
{
   public string SchetNum {get;set;}
   public string SchetCode {get;set;}
   public string OstatokNachGod {get;set;}
   public string VPutiNachGod {get;set;}
   public string OstatokKonetsGod {get;set;}
   public string VPutiKonetsGod {get;set;}
}
```

Разумеется вы используете конкретный тип данных, string для примера.

Далее вам нужна структура классов.
У некоторых будут специальные атрибуты:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="SchemaVersion")]
public class SchemaVersion { 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Number")] 
    public int Number { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Column")]
public class Column { 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Name")] 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Num")] 
    public int Num { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Px")]
public class Px { 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Num")] 
    public int Num { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Value")] 
    public string Value { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Data")]
public class Data { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Px")] 
    public List<Px> Px { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="СТРОКА")] 
    public int СТРОКА { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Document")]
public class Document { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Data")] 
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="ПлСч11")] 
    public int ПлСч11 { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Form")]
public class Form { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Column")] 
    public List<Column> Column { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Document")] 
    public List<Document> Document { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Code")] 
    public int Code { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Status")] 
    public int Status { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Name")] 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Source")]
public class Source { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Form")] 
    public Form Form { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Code")] 
    public int Code { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="ClassCode")] 
    public string ClassCode { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Period")]
public class Period { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Source")] 
    public Source Source { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Date")] 
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="RootXml")]
public class RootXml { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="SchemaVersion")] 
    public SchemaVersion SchemaVersion { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Period")] 
    public Period Period { get; set; } 
}
```

Дальше обходите свои коллекции с UseFullData и распихивая нужные строки/таблицы по классам, и в конце всего-лишь сериализуете RootXml:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootXml));
FileStream fs = new FileStream("my.xml",FileMode.Create);
ser.Serialize(fs,myGroup);
fs.Close();
```